# XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ) returns Fatal error: Failed to initialize XMSFactoryFactory

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, xms

I'm trying to connect to an IBM message queue using .net and MQ client v8.0.0.5 but I keep receiving the following error:

> Fatal error. Failed to initialize XMSFactoryFactory
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.XMS.Client.Impl, Version=8.0.0.5,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"IBM.XMS.Client.Impl, Version=8.0.0.5, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=d2666ab12fca862b

Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed MQ Client v8.0.0.5 (x64) on my machine.
- Referenced the following assemblies:
- amqmdnet.dll
- amqmdnsp.dll
- amqmdxcs.dll
- IBM.XMS.dll
- IBM.XMS.Admin.dll
- IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.dll
- IBM.XMS.NLS.dll
- IBM.XMS.Provider.dll
- IBM.XMS.Util.dll

Now I also have version v7.5.0.4 installed on my machine and that is having no issues connecting to the queue.

One more thing I noticed is there are no assemblies for v8.0.0.5 in the GAC but the assemblies for v7.5.0.4 are present. Can that be the reason?

Unfortunately, I cannot remove v7.5.0.4 until have both the versions working normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MQ v8.0.0.5 XMS .NET assemblies not being in the GAC is most likely the cause.

You can look at the alternative of using redirection, update app.config file to use the correct version of assemblies your application requires. Look into your MQ installation directory for a file called `NonPrimaryRedirect.config`. This file contains sample configuration required for application to look for a specific version of MQ/XMS .NET assembly. Copy the contents of this file to your application's app.config file and try. You must ensure all `href` attributes point to correct path.

Comment: This did it for me. Once I updated the app.config to add the file reference for 'IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.dll', the code started throwing up the same error for other assemblies. After I added them one by one, the code started throwing a different error which, I failed to note down. Post that I ran the 'amqiRegisterdotNet.cmd' in the MQ folder to register v8.0.0.5 assemblies to GAC. After that, I received yet another error which I resolved by adding the assembly 'amqmdnet.dll' to app.config, same way I did for the other ones. Problem solved, I'm now able to read/write messages to the queue.